# Duda con ejercicios con mapas Java

Tags: java

Suponga que existe un diccionario tendencias con un string que representa una fecha (mm-dd-aaaa)
como clave y como valor un conjunto de las etiquetas (hashtags) que fueron tendencias en Twitter para esa fecha. 
Por ejemplo:

> tendencias = {‘08-22-2016’:{‘#Rio2016’, ‘#BSC’, ‘#ECU’},
>   ’08-25-2016’:{‘#GYE’, ‘#BRA’}, …, ‘08-27- 2016’:{‘#YoSoyEspol’,
>   ‘#GYE’, ‘#BSC’}}

Implemente:

a) reportaTendencias(tendencias, listaFechas) que recibe el diccionario de tendencias y una lista con
strings que representan fechas (mm-dd-aaaa). La función debe mostrar por pantalla:

- 1) Las etiquetas que fueron tendencia todas las fechas en listaFechas
- 2) Las etiquetas que fueron tendencia al menos en una de las fechas en listaFechas

---

```
 public static void reportaTendencias(HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>> 
     m, LinkedList<String> l) {
            for (String clave : m.keySet()) {
                for (String valor : m.get(clave)) {
                System.out.println("fecha: " + clave + "," + "etiquetas: " + valor);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hice esto para el literal 1 y funciona pero no se si es eficiente y el 2 no estoy segura como hacerlo.

b)tendenciasExcluyentes(tendencias, fecha1, fecha2) que recibe el diccionario de tendencias y dos
strings que representan fechas (mm-dd-aaaa). La función debe mostrar por pantalla las etiquetas
que fueron tendencias o en fecha1 o en fecha2, pero no en las dos. Nota: suponga que fecha1 y
fecha2 existen en el diccionario como claves.

```
  public static void tendenciasExcluyentes(HashMap<String, 
 LinkedList<String>> m, String fecha1, String fecha2) {
       LinkedList<String> lista = new LinkedList();
        if (m.containsKey(fecha1)) {
             System.out.println(m.get(fecha1));
       }
   }
 }
```

Y para este no estoy segura como seguir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estabas planteando mal el problema.Por un lado, tienes que utilizar la lista de fechas que te pasan por parametro.

Como imagino que es parte de ejercicio de pruebas de estructuras, aquí te paso una solución usando la misma estructura con fines auxiliares.

/*
    a) reportaTendencias(tendencias, listaFechas) que recibe el diccionario de tendencias y una lista con strings que representan fechas (mm-dd-aaaa). La función debe mostrar por pantalla:

```
1) Las etiquetas que fueron tendencia todas las fechas en listaFechas
2) Las etiquetas que fueron tendencia al menos en una de las fechas en listaFechas

 */
public static void reportaTendencias(Map<String, LinkedList<String>> m, LinkedList<String> l) {
    System.out.println("Ejercicio A, apartado 1");
    // Recorrermos las fechas que nos pasan por parametro
    Map<String, Integer> coincidencias = new HashMap<>(); //Recuerda que en Maps la Key no puede repetirse
    for (String clave : l) {
        //Obtenemos el valor asociado a la clave de la fecha
        for (String valor : m.get(clave)) {
            // Si el valor ya existe en nuestro mapeo coincidencias, simplemente aumentamos el numero de veces encontrado
            if (coincidencias.containsKey(valor)) {
                coincidencias.put(valor, coincidencias.get(valor) + 1);
            } else {
                // En caso contrario debemos meter el valor nuevo
                coincidencias.put(valor, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    // Imprimimos solo aquellos valores que hayan aparecido en TODAS las fechas
    for (String valor : coincidencias.keySet()) {
        if (coincidencias.get(valor) == l.size()) {
            System.out.print(valor + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    //Recorremos la lista de fechas y guardamos el valor
    System.out.println("Ejercicio A, apartado 2");
    coincidencias.clear();
    for (String clave : l) {
        for (String valor : m.get(clave)) {
            coincidencias.put(valor, 1);
        }
    }

    // Imprimimos los valores una unica vez
    for (String valor : coincidencias.keySet()) {
        System.out.print(valor + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void tendenciasExcluyentes(Map<String, LinkedList<String>> m, String fecha1, String fecha2) {
    System.out.println("Ejercicio B");
    Map<String, Integer> coincidencias = new HashMap<>(); //Recuerda que en Maps la Key no puede repetirse
    for (String clave : m.keySet()) {
        //Solo comprobaremos aquellos que coincidan con las fechas pasadas por parametro
        if (clave.equals(fecha1) || clave.equals(fecha2)) {
            for (String valor : m.get(clave)) {
                // Si el valor ya existe en nuestro mapeo coincidencias, simplemente aumentamos el numero de veces encontrado
                if (coincidencias.containsKey(valor)) {
                    coincidencias.put(valor, coincidencias.get(valor) + 1);
                } else {
                    // En caso contrario debemos meter el valor nuevo
                    coincidencias.put(valor, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // NOTA: Ponemos 1 porque solo permitimos que apareza una vez
    for (String valor : coincidencias.keySet()) {
        if (coincidencias.get(valor) == 1) {
            System.out.print(valor + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona bien y lo entendi mejor :)